# How do I get TV out working on an ATI X800 GTO²?

Tags: 11.10, ati, graphics, tv

Is there any way to make my graphics card (ATI x800) work with tvout?
I know there are no proprietary drivers for this card only the opensource ones.
It uses this cable for video out:

http://warningdang.dynalias.com/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x265/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/3/a31b_1.jpg

Personally I use the yellow RCA for tvout (in windows).
I hope there is a way to work it out because it's a really important feature for me and one of the only reasons I boot windows.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: If i'm not mistaken that's an S-Video out, does it work if you simply plug the RCA in to the TV? perhaps you may want to use the S-video connector.

Comment: I know how to connect it because it works for me in windows. My question is how or if I can configure tvout with this card under ubuntu while I have only opensource drivers for this card? Simplified: How do I "tell" the graphics card to output to my tv?

Answer (score 2):

[From the X.Org Wiki:](http://www.x.org/wiki/radeonTV)

You can enable TV-Out either dynamically (by issuing commands to the running X server) or statically (through the xorg.config file, before starting the X server). For testing, the dynamic method is probably easier.

**Enabling TV-Out Dynamically**

TV-out may be enabled by using a recent driver and xrandr utility:

```
xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600

xrandr --output S-video --mode 800x600

xrandr --output S-video --set tv_standard ntsc
```

**Enabling TV-Out Statically**

Several options need to be specified. See the radeon(4) manpage for a description. In particular, you must set "TVStandard" to match your flavour of video.

This recipe is not definitive, but it has worked.

In the "Device" section:

```
   Driver  "radeon"
   Option "TVDACLoadDetect" "TRUE"
   Option "TVStandard" "ntsc"
   Option "monitor-S-video" "TV-monitor"
```

In the "Monitor" Section:

```
   Option  "PreferredMode"  "800x600"
```

In the "Screen" section:

```
    DefaultDepth  24
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth          24
            Modes         "800x600"
    EndSubSection
```

Comment: When I execute this in the terminal:

xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600

xrandr --output S-video --mode 800x600

My PC LCD "turns off" but still the tv shows nothing (I checked the cable conecction).

Also when I do: xrandr -q in the terminal one of the line says:
S-video disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
But again it is connected physically.

Comment: Yes the PC screen will turn off because what it does is to make the S-video the only output.

Comment: But as I said, the tv doesn't change (still doesn't show anything).